# Database tables with large number of columns

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a database in two versions, but with the same structure and data: one for a website (SQL Server and VB.Net) and for an android app (Xamarin and SQLite). I have doubts about the structure of a part of the data.

I have a list of objects (rows in my table) with a long list of associated fields (Length, Weight, Color, ...) as columns. The number of columns is higher than 100, and not all columns are filled for all objects; in practice there are a lot of null values.

My idea was to split the table into 3 new ones: the first containing the always present main feature, the second with the less frequent columns (in the rows) and the third something like a Pivot.

- Table 1: ObjectID, Name, Barcode, …
- Table 2: FeatureID, FeatureName
- Table 3: ObjectID, FeatureID, FeatureValue

Is the select query performance the same? Are there any differences between SQL Server and SQLite? Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Your new approach is called EAV - entity attribute value. It's not BAD per se, but it has own problems, about which there are a lot of articles, blogs and tik toks about. You're doing a kind of hybrid model, which i think is a better idea than a full on EAV, keep only the extra properties there. Of course doing this will affect the queries, usually negatively, since you need more joins / pivots etc to get the values, but you might save a lot of row data. In SQL Server there's a thing called sparse columns which might allevate some of the problems you have with a lot of NULLs.

Comment: The most positive upside is that you can have multiple property values per "column" of object, which is harder to do with columns and lead to things like (attribute1, attribute2...) as well as more flexibility when it comes to adding new entities.

Comment: Another possibility is to store properties in a JSON column. SQL-Server has direct support for it, SQLite has indirect support through JSON functions.

Comment: There are many folks here who see EAV as evil.  I do not.  Sometimes it is the prudent choice, especially if you have ever evolving attributes.

Comment: You might wanna look into columnstore as well, it still uses the "column" model, but the data is stored per column, which i think would save you a lot of space and improve performance without going the full EAV mode

Comment: Considering your suggestions, probably the best approach is to divide my data in two categories as I have already done, using an hybrid solution. I'll surely study le EAV approach as suggested, even if I don't exclude to use JSON in future, when I'll have more time for development

Answer (score 0):

The general considerations about designing databases are :

- NO NULL
- NO DUPLICATE
- ATOMIC VALUES
- Any modification (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE..) of ONE information must not affect more than ONE row...

This leads to [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)....

Each time you violate those principles you will have peformances problems. Because thoses technics have been created to reduce data access !

In your single table with 100 columns you will never be able to optimize the data access with indexes, because the number of indexes to do so is over 100! (factorial 100).

The exact number of indexes you should have to be sure that any query will be fast with BTree indexes is :
[image]
where n = 100

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand well. My DB matches the general rules you mentioned.
The 100 columns are independent and numeric. It's just that sometimes the operator has recorded the value and sometimes not, but the most important ones are usually there.
Do I have to deduce that it is better not to have the 100 columns and therefore a different approach?

Comment: When you say "sometimes", that means other of your 100 columns will have NULL. A good design drive to have absolutly no NULL inside the tables....